# Linux How to copy symbolic link and preserve date

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I have a directory with this kind of file:

```
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 utges_m gid36     12 May 17  2011 libedit.so -> libedit.so.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 utges_m gid36     16 Apr 16  2009 libedit.so.2 -> libedit.so.2.0.9
352 -rw-r--r--  1 utges_m gid36 358958 Mar 10  2010 libedit.so.2.0.9
```

I would like to copy file and symlink and preserve date.

I started with this command:

```
  cp -dp sourceDir/* destinationDir
```

and the result is:

```
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 siri gid33     12 Jul  9 16:38 libedit.so -> libedit.so.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 siri gid33     16 Jul  9 16:38 libedit.so.2 -> libedit.so.2.0.9
356 -rw-r--r--  1 siri gid33 358958 Mar 10  2010 libedit.so.2.0.9
```

So, I wrote this simple bash script:

```
 cp -dp $OLDDIR/* $NEWDIR

 ls $OLDDIR | while read f; do {
    TS=$(stat -c '%Y' "$OLDDIR/$f")
    DATE=$(date -d "UTC 1970-01-01 $TS secs")
    echo "$f  $DATE"
    touch -d "${DATE}" "$NEWDIR/$f"
 } done;
```

The script output is:

```
 libedit.so  Tue May 17 21:35:14 CEST 2011
 libedit.so.2  Thu Apr 16 10:30:05 CEST 2009
 libedit.so.2.0.9  Wed Mar 10 16:31:17 CET 2010
```

but unfortunately the result is:

```
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 siri gid33     12 Jul  9 16:55 libedit.so -> libedit.so.2
  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 siri gid33     16 Jul  9 16:55 libedit.so.2 -> libedit.so.2.0.9
356 -rw-r--r--  1 siri gid33 358958 Mar 10  2010 libedit.so.2.0.9
```

What's wrong with what I did?

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **system may not support changing timestamps of symbolic links**, given that `cp -dp` *should* have worked to begin with.

Also, if you do use **`touch`**, you must **add the (GNU `touch`) `-h` option to target the *link* rather than its target**:

From `man touch` - note the statement in parentheses:

```
-h, --no-dereference
  affect each symbolic link instead of any referenced file
  (useful only on systems that can change the timestamps of a symlink)
```

Try `touch -h <someSymlink>; ls -l <someSymlink>` to see if it works in principle.

Comment: Thaks a lot, I think you're right. The suggested command output is: `touch: invalid option -- h`.

Comment: You're welcome, but just to be sure: are you actually using _GNU_ `touch`? What does `touch --version` return? `invalid option` suggests that the option is not supported _at all_ (not part of the syntax), but, I guess, it's possible it was removed from the GNU `touch` version on your system.

Comment: This is the output of `touch --version`: `touch (coreutils) 5.2.1` and the output of `uname -a` is: `Linux itmi01vl100.milano.it 2.6.9-78.0.1.ELsmp #1 SMP Tue Jul 22 18:11:48 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux `

Comment: I guess it depends on release 4. I tried `cp -dp` command on "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)" and it works. Thaks again.

Comment: @Letizia: My pleasure; thanks for posting your additional findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rsync instead:

`rsync -av /folder/ /newfolder/`

example:

```
mkdir folder; ln -s /etc/hosts /tmp/folder/testfile

rsync -av /tmp/folder/ /tmp/newfolder/
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/newfolder
./
testfile -> /etc/hosts

sent 75 bytes  received 18 bytes  186.00 bytes/sec
total size is 10  speedup is 0.11

ls -l /tmp/folder/ 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tiago tiago 10 Jul  9 16:44 testfile -> /etc/hosts

ls -l /tmp/newfolder/ 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tiago tiago 10 Jul  9 16:44 testfile -> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not work. I had the same result as described previously.

Comment: sorry to hear that, the `-a` is for archive it should not change permissions nor modification date,BTW cp also offers `-a` give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it the hard way? What you need is `cp -a`. For example in ~/lib I have:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 david david    13 May 28 05:59 libetf.so -> libetf.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 david david    13 May 28 05:59 libetf.so.1 -> libetf.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 david david  8512 May 28 05:59 libetf.so.1.0
```

To copy and preserve date:

```
$ md lib2

$ cp -a lib/libetf* lib2

$ ls -al lib2
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 david david  4096 Jul  9 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 110 david david 12288 Jul  9 11:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 david david    13 May 28 05:59 libetf.so -> libetf.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 david david    13 May 28 05:59 libetf.so.1 -> libetf.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 david david  8512 May 28 05:59 libetf.so.1.0
```